# JavaScript remove white spaces after applying regex with match()

Tags: javascript, regex

any idea on how to remove the annoying white space after the apostrophe and before the period / full stop after having applied regex with match() ? 
The result should be a string with no "unnecessary" spaces. 
Thanks a lot.

```
var text = "There’s no doubt these days.";
var r = text.match(/\w+|[^'\s\w]+/g);
var j = r.join(" ");
console.log(j);

// the result: There ’ s no doubt lives these days .
// should be: There’s no doubt lives these days.
```

Comment: Instead, you could use text.split(' ');

Comment: It seems to be an X Y problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It is really surprising how the word "lives" got in there.

Comment: Thanks for your unnecessary comments. split() doesn't take into account periods roland, and Toto, isn't the explanation clear enough for you ? I've provided the examples and told you what I expect as the outcome. Yes, I should've removed "lives". Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var text = "There’s no doubt these days.";
var r = text.match(/\w+|[^'\s\w]+/g);
var j = r.join(" ")
  .replace(" ’ ", "’")
  .replace(" .", ".");
console.log(j);
```

Comment: Thanks Shreevardhan, it works and it will do. Isn't there a more "apply to all" solution however ? Thank you.

Comment: @user1627930 for an **apply to all** solution, you need to rewrite the regular expression to ignore all possible characters not supposed to get surrounded by whitespace, or elaborate your use case.

Comment: I tried to do it (to manipulate the regex)  but I failed. I didn't find a pattern that would satisfy my need.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to get rid of multiple spaces in between the words but leave punctuation intact? You can either change your regex to:

```
var r = text.match(/\S+/g);
```

Or just replace multiple spaces with 1 with .replace

```
var text = "There’s    no   doubt         these   days.";
text = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");

console.log(text);
```